# Can i use a 5v water pump as a vacuum pump to lift very light objects?

Tags: water, pump, vacuum

I want to use a small water pump (3.7v or 5v - the aquarium ones - 12v at most) as a vacuum pump: i need it to lift an object that weights 5 grams at most. Can it be done or the pump will just overheat? I was planning to use a very small hose.

Comment: Why not use a small vacuum pump (or aquarium air pump that you alter slightly) rather than a water pump which probably won't pump air well, if at all?

Comment: @Ecnerwal it will tale 1-2 weeks for the water pump that i need to arrive from the ebay seller... and i already have an air pump laying around here unused.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about home improvement

Comment: @mmathis it actually is. I am trying to build a FarmBot.

Comment: May be more appropriate on the gardening stack then

Comment: There are little diaphragm pumps that will do the trick.  I've got one of [these](https://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/en/vacuum-pump-12v.html), which is bigger than you need.  Otherwise *some* aquarium air pumps can be modified to suck instead of blowing (basically find a way to connect a hose to the inlet)

Answer (score 1):

When you say a water pump, do you literally mean a pump designed to move water? If so, then no. Don't bother.

While technically it could have enough suction to do what you want, it is not designed for this application and using a water pump dry will absolutely burn it out (at different lengths of time, from minutes, to hours, to unknown). Depending on the cost of the unit, and the warranty or engineering the manufacturer put in to it (not to mention the parts itself), it could last quite a while. However, most manufacturers have become quite adept at materials manufacturing as their goal is to use as little material as possible, at the least amount of production cost while not producing something "cheap" (to the point people wont rely on it). So a water pump is almost certainly expecting a liquid for cooling. Not to mention the pump mechanism is shaped to move liquid.

This is a scenario where using the proper type of pump for the proper application would in the long run save you money and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Water pumps are often centrifugal pumps; centrifugal pumps do not move air very well, and you need to move air. If you research the type of pump that you have you might get a better idea of whether or not it will work for your application.

OR... just try it out, what do you have to lose? If it doesn't work then you get the correct type of pump, typically a positive-displacement pump.